# How do I write the class that contains the main function for this code?

Tags: java

```
public class Soldier
{
     private String soldierName;              
     public void setSoldierName( String name )      
     {                                             
        SoldierName = name;
     }
     public String getSoldierName()        
     {                                    
        return soldierName;                
     }
     public void displayMessage()
     {
        System.out.printf( "The name of \n%s!\n",
           getSoldierName() );
     }
}
```

Comment: "*How do I write the class*" - One option is a keyboard.

Answer (score 2):

If you just want the class to have a `main` method, just add it as you would to any other class:

```
public class Soldier
{
     private String soldierName;              
     public void setSoldierName( String name )      
     {                                             
        SoldierName = name;
     }
     public String getSoldierName()        
     {                                    
        return soldierName;                
     }
     public void displayMessage()
     {
        System.out.printf( "The name of \n%s!\n",
           getSoldierName() );
     }
     public static void main(String args[]) {
     }

}
```

To actually do something useful in the `main`, you might want to create an instance of the class in there, set the soldier name and then call the `displayMessage()` method, for example. So like this:

```
     public static void main(String args[]) {
         Soldier soldier = new Soldier();
         soldier.setSoldierName("John");
         soldier.displayMessage();
     }
```

Comment: While this question is correct, we should avoid providing answers to questions that don't demonstrate minimal understanding. Though, +1 this time for the explanation.

Comment: Ok, good point. Noted.

Comment: i understand thanx let me try it thanx a million?